# When I use asp LoginView Role for Button then get an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, loginview

I am using the below code in ASP.NET to hide action buttons for simple users who can see only data but can't change it;

```
<asp:LoginView ViewStateMode="Disabled" runat="server">
    <RoleGroups>
        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="HRAdmin">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="BtnAddnew" CssClass="bluebutton" title="Click to Add New Employee" runat="server" Text="Add New" OnClick="BtnAddnew_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="BtnSaveNew" CssClass="bluebutton" title="Click to Save New Record" runat="server" Text="Save New" Visible="false" OnClick="BtnSaveNew_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="BtnUpdate" CssClass="bluebutton" title="Click to Update Record" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="BtnUpdate_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="BtnSaveUpdate" CssClass="bluebutton" title="Click to Save Record" runat="server" Text="Save Update" Visible="false" OnClick="BtnSaveUpdate_Click" />                   
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:RoleGroup>
    </RoleGroups>
</asp:LoginView>
```

But when I load page or build project, then I get errors:

> The name 'BtnAddnew' does not exist in the current context.
>
> The name 'BtnSaveNew' does not exist in the current context.
>
> The name 'BtnUpdate' does not exist in the current context.
>
> The name 'BtnSaveUpdate' does not exist in the current context.

It means in the C# code it is not loading `OnClick` event of these buttons. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because I am using `<asp:LoginView` and buttons was inside it.That's why you may use below code:

> ```
> Button BtnAddnew = ((Button)(this.LVButton.FindControl("BtnAddnew")));
> Button BtnSaveNew = ((Button)(this.LVButton.FindControl("BtnSaveNew")));
> Button BtnUpdate = ((Button)(this.LVButton.FindControl("BtnUpdate")));
> Button BtnSaveUpdate = ((Button)(this.LVButton.FindControl("BtnSaveUpdate")));
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This suggests that you don't in code behind
have the button click events.

Try removing the this part of each button:

So, change:

```
 <asp:Button ID="BtnAddnew" CssClass="bluebutton" 
    title="Click to Add New Employee" runat="server" 
   Text="Add New" OnClick="BtnAddnew_Click" />
```

to:

```
  <asp:Button ID="BtnAddnew" CssClass="bluebutton" 
    title="Click to Add New Employee" runat="server"
    Text="Add New" />
```

Now, do a build-rebuild Solution

If you want to add a click event to each button, then in markup, type on OnClick=, and THEN let intel-sense suggest to you to create new event (a click event)

eg this:

[image]

It will seem like nothing occurred, but if you flip over to code behind, then the button click event should now exist.

In fact, before you try any of above, exit VS. Re-load. Do a bio;d ->rebuild solution. Then try the page - it it still don't work, then you need to do above.

Comment: I have coded all button's events like this;


`protected void BtnAddnew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BtnAddnew.Visible = false;
            BtnSaveNew.Visible = true;
            BtnUpdate.Visible = false;
            BtnSaveUpdate.Visible = false;
            DDLCurrentOffice.Items.Clear();
            DDLCurrentOffice.Items.Add(li);
            ClearItems();
            EnableItems();
            SetFocus(txtName);
        }`

but here in C# code it says `BtnAddnew` did not exist.

Comment: This is because I'm using `asp:LoginView` for `User Role` and when I removed `asp:LoginView` before and after from these buttons then application works fine. But I must need `asp:LoginView` .

Comment: And if you remove the onclick events from the markup - does that work? It should be fine. I was able to just cut + paste your markup into a sample page - and it worked just fine without the click events in the markup - and I included the RoleGroup tags. And edit your code - don't try and post in comments. Your event stubs look wrong here. As I stated, delete the click events, and then re-generate them by selecting the create new event. but first remove the click events from markup - does it work? if yes, then use create new event as outlined in above.

Answer (score 0):

```html
you should check you aspx page cs refrence class.

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Test/Test/Test.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test_Update.aspx.cs" Inherits="ProjectName_FolderName_Test_Update" %>
```